# Should 'good' answers to questions asked by inactive users be automatically accepted?

Tags: discussion

It occurred to me whilst looking through some of the 'unanswered' questions that some of them have been answered, but the answer just hasn't been accepted because the user is inactive. I'm fairly new to SE forums, so was wondering what the policy is here? Is there are time-frame after which an answer may be accepted by a moderator?

I only ask because this will clearly be affecting the proportion of questions answered! Not massively I know, but it's a problem that will only increase as site-traffic also increases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Moderators cannot accept answers on behalf of users. There are various reminders for users to accept answers to their questions, but if they don't do it there is nothing we moderators can do about it.

Answers with at least +1 score are counted as answered for the "unanswered" tab, and I think for the answer rate as well.

Comment: Oh OK, thanks for that. Just demonstrating my ignorance apparently!

Comment: The problem I have with people not accepting answers that are good enough is that the person who wrote the answer doesn't get the credit they deserve for putting effort in - think there should be some way for moderators to step in, say minimum 5 upvotes & questions over 6 months old + no effect of email reminders to OP.

Comment: I was about to ask the same question and found that it had been answered. I guess the thing to do is to scan the list from time to time and upvote any reasonable questions to reward the answerer and clear the list.