# Accept answer reminder when OP upvotes?

Tags: feature-request

I have noticed a couple of times that when I answer a question it is fairly obvious the original poster (OP) has upvoted my answer but they then don't accept the answer - looking at when they were last seen and when you get upvoted is a fairly good clue. It seems most often to occur with new/low usage members hence I'd suggest that sometimes they don't know that they are supposed to press accept if an answer is satisfactory. This leaves some questions as "unanswered" when really they are answered which [isn't good for the site](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272/should-good-answers-to-questions-asked-by-inactive-users-be-automatically-acce/273#273).

So as a potential solution **would it be possible to have Stack Exchange recognise when a user upvotes an answer to the question they posted and then remind them with a speech bubble or popup window to also accept if the answer is good?** (popups could be just like the one that comes up when you try to change a vote a while after your original vote and tells you the post must be edited before you can change vote).

Comment: I think all answers with +1 count as answered in the site statistics (e.g. not found under the 'unanswered' tab), see [this meta](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/272/should-good-answers-to-questions-asked-by-inactive-users-be-automatically-acce/273#273). However, I generally agree that answers should be accepted if satisfactory.

Comment: I have found (at least on StackOverflow) that a friendly reminder in a comment to your answer for the OP to select your answer as the accepted one often works well, especially if they've already left a comment thanking you for the answer, whether or not they upvoted it.

Comment: @MattDMo I've done that a few times here - there are some answers of mine that have been well upvoted but the OP hasn't accepted even with a bit of prompting e.g. http://tinyurl.com/ofodd9e

Comment: I am not too bothered about the points but I think it is nice to have an answer accepted to show OP recognise the effort some people go to, I know I answer some questions well outside my expertise which requires a lot of work and reading around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Users who have less than 1000 rep [should already receive a pop-up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69777/176080) similar to this one after they upvote an answer on their own question:

[image: Don't forget you can mark this as the accepted answer by clicking its check mark]

It could be that users are not taking the hint, or it could be that the reputation threshold is different on non-graduated sites (which might need to be looked at by the SE team).